# Looking up a cross-reference but a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I hope you can help me please.

How would I go about looking up data in the following cross-reference table?

I have the header row (i.e. 25) value and the column (mm) value and want to return the x/y value. i.e I have and item with (header row) X = 25 and (mm) Y= 0.48 item and want 1.6 to be returned.

```
+--------------+-------+---------+---------+---------+
| (mm)   width | 10~20 | 20.1~30 | 30.1~40 | 40.1~50 |
+--------------+-------+---------+---------+---------+
| 0.20~0.45    |  1.3  |   1.8   |   2.1   |   3.5   |
| 0.46~0.60    |  1.4  |   1.6   |   1.8   |   2.3   |
| 0.61~0.70    |  1.5  |   1.7   |   1.6   |   2.1   |
| 0.71~0.80    |  0.7  |   1.1   |   2.2   |   3.1   |
+--------------+-------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: Did you mean **25** as X?

Answer (score 3):

Try,

```
=INDEX(B2:E5, MATCH(TEXT(H2, "0.00"), A2:A5), MATCH(TEXT(G2, "0"), B1:E1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With your current set up:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((G2>=--LEFT(B1:E1,FIND("~",B1:E1)-1))*(G2<=--MID(B1:E1,FIND("~",B1:E1)+1,2))*(G3<=--MID(A2:A5,FIND("~",A2:A5)+1,3))*(G3>=--LEFT(A2:A5,FIND("~",A2:A5)-1)),B2:E5)
```

[image]

---

But if you modify the numbers a little to just include the minimums:

[image]

This simpler formula will work:

```
=INDEX(B2:E5,MATCH(G2,B1:E1),MATCH(G3,A2:A5))
```

[image]